# Why framelayout content disappear when relativelayout expand

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have activity that shows search bar. I am not using appbarlayout as it has rendering issue with my latest version of Android studio. When i click search button my recyclerview which is in a framelayout disappears. Do i need to attach and detach when i press search button?

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvUQQ.gif)

**activity_rating.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.view.RatingActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/lblAdvancedSearch"
                style="@style/AppTheme.AppCompatTextView_1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_grey_500"
                android:drawablePadding="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/lbl_AdvancedSearch"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:id="@+id/AdvancedSearchForm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout_TerminalID"
                        style="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout_1"
                        android:hint="@string/lbl_TerminalID"
                        app:counterEnabled="true"
                        app:counterMaxLength="@integer/terminal_id_input_length"
                        app:errorEnabled="true"
                        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/TextInputEditText_TerminalID"
                            style="@style/AppTheme.EditTextLayout_1"

                            />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout_BranchCode"
                        style="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout_1"
                        android:hint="Branch Code"
                        app:counterEnabled="true"
                        app:counterMaxLength="@integer/terminal_id_input_length"
                        app:errorEnabled="true"
                        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/TextInputEditText_BranchCode"
                            style="@style/AppTheme.EditTextLayout_1" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout_DepartmentCode"
                        style="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout_1"
                        android:hint="@string/lbl_DepartmentCode"
                        app:counterEnabled="true"
                        app:counterMaxLength="@integer/terminal_id_input_length"
                        app:errorEnabled="true"
                        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/TextInputEditText_DepartmentCode"
                            style="@style/AppTheme.EditTextLayout_1" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout_StaffID"
                        style="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout_1"
                        android:hint="@string/lbl_StaffID"
                        app:counterEnabled="true"
                        app:counterMaxLength="@integer/terminal_id_input_length"
                        app:errorEnabled="true"
                        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/TextInputEditText_StaffID"
                            style="@style/AppTheme.EditTextLayout_1" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/MaterialButton_Search"
                        style="@style/AppTheme.MaterialButton_1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/md_purple_700"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
                        android:drawableTint="@color/md_white_1000"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_btnSearch"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000" />
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentsContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

**RatingActivity.java**

```
package com.action_and_notification.ui.view;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import com.action_and_notification.R;
import com.action_and_notification.databinding.ActivityRatingBinding;


public class RatingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityRatingBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_rating);
        binding.lblAdvancedSearch.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (binding.AdvancedSearchForm.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                binding.AdvancedSearchForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (binding.AdvancedSearchForm.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                binding.AdvancedSearchForm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentsContainer) != null) {

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            RatingList_Fragment ratingList_fragment = new RatingList_Fragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentsContainer, ratingList_fragment).commit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why i am are receiving negative star

Comment: anyone who can help me?